# Imported python module overrides option parser

Tags: python, google-oauth, argparse, optparse

I have written a python utility script that uses optparse to include options and flags at script launch.

Everything works great, but when I import google API oauth2client and run its execute function, it overrides my `add_options` into the options it uses.

When I say 'overrides' I mean that even though my script add options to my option parser, when I execute the script like so:

```
./myscript --help
```

I get a detailed response of the options I added to my script:

```
Usage: myscript [options]

Options:
    -h, --help            show this help message and exit
    -u USER, --user=USER  resources owned by this username
```

But, when I actually execute my script like so:

```
./myscript --user myuser
```

I get the following error:

```
usage: smyscript [-h] [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
               [--noauth_local_webserver]
               [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT     
               [AUTH_HOST_PORT  ...]]]
               [--logging_level 
               {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
 myscript: error: unrecognized arguments: --user myuser
```

Another important thing to know is that I'm using my own module that wraps oauth2client like so:

```
import oauth2client
import argparse

def execute():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description=__doc__,
            formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
            parents=[tools.argparser])
            # don't use any flags                                                                           
    flags = parser.parse_args(None)

    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
             client_secret_path,
             scope=scope_path,
             message=tools.message_if_missing(client_secret))
    # open credential storage path                                                                                                                                                                 
     credential_storage =  file.Storage(self._credential_storage_path)
     credentials = credential_storage.get()
     # get credentails if necessary                                                                                                                                                                 
     if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
          credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, credential_storage, flags)
```

Then my script looks something like that:

```
import myown_oauth2client_wrapper

from optparse import OptionParser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    usage = "something"
    parser_ = OptionParser(usage)

    parser_.add_option("-u","--user")
    (options_, args) = parser_.parse_args()

    myown_oauth2client_wrapper.execute()
```

How can I avoid this option override?

Shahar

Comment: Be more specific about the errors you get.  I doubt if it is changing your `parser_`.  More likely it is implementing its own parser (based on `argparse`), and parsing the same `sys.argv`.  The error message will give a clue.  There are have been other `argparse` questions involving the `google` `api`.

Comment: How about telling us which module you are importing, what function you are calling and why you think `add_option` has been overriden?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question and since poster won't even tell us which function is being called, it needs to be closed.

Comment: Hey @tdelaney , thanks for your reply. I have edited my question to add missing details. hope It is better now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a previous question, [Getting Youtube data using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818753/getting-youtube-data-using-python)

I found that the google api uses `argparse`.

```
from outh2client.tools import argparser
```

<strike>My deduction is that it is parsing the `sys.argv` when imported.</strike>

As I asked in the comment, we need to know what errors you are getting. What do mean by 'overrides'?  What's the indication of that?  Are you getting a parser error message, the kind produced by `argparse` or `optparse`?  If so, what message.

Show us the commandline that gives the error, along with the error message.

You might want to call the script with `-h` to see who/what prints parsing help message.

---

So `tools.argparser` is an `argparse` parser with those `auth` and `logging` arguments defined.  In the question I answered earlier, the user used that parser directly (with an addition of their own).  You are using that parser as a `parent`.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...
        parents=[tools.argparser])                                                                    
flags = parser.parse_args(None)
```

It now parses `sys.argv`.  Since `--user` was not defined for this parser, it raises the `myscript: error: unrecognized arguments: --user myuser`.

One solution is to use:

```
flags, extras = parser.parse_known_args(None)
```

Now I expect it to run, and for `extras` to equal `['--user', 'myuser']`.

Another option is to define a `--user` argument for this `parser`.

```
parser.add_argument('-u','--user',help='dummy user argument')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical problem. The problem happens because the google authorization module also uses argparse. What you should achieve is not to share that memory space. I solved it by receiving the arguments via argparse, loading them into another object, but then before calling google modules I did the following:

```
import sys


sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]]
```

and my problem was solved.